# Wilcoxon signed-rank test on cross-validated values

Tags: classification, cross-validation, permutation-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Many neuroscience papers aim to estimate the significance of classification accuracy measures (AUC-ROC for example): can one classify such behaviors better than chance with such neuronal activities? To this end, Wilcoxon signed-rank tests are often used, with pairs of cross-validated classification accuracy values before and after shuffling behavioral labels.

Yet Wilcoxon signed-rank test assumes independence between pairs of values. Isn't this assumption necessarily violated when dealing with cross-validated measures? Are permutation tests more appropriate with cross-validated measures?